# Why different mobile sites open with m extention

Tags: responsive

Why different mobile sites open with m extention. e.g: https://m.youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

m(Dot) design is the original solution for mobile visitors. Before m(Dot) design came along, mobile visitors had to wait while the entire site loaded and then struggle to navigate a design and UX made for desktop visitors.

Today, it’s hard to imagine a site that doesn’t have any sort of mobile solution.

With m(Dot) design, you must create a separate version of your site specifically optimized for mobile users.

Responsive design is a newer solution to the mobile visitor issue. Instead of having to create an entirely separate site, you can simply create one version that is responsive to different screen sizes using media queries.

m(Dot) sites were created because, well, they’re better than trying to load the full desktop version of a site on a mobile device. They were also pretty easy to create, which means they won’t take up too many resources.

Unfortunately, there’s a laundry list of problems that comes along with doing something the fast and cheap way…

- You need to manage and optimize two separate sites.
- The redirect causes a slower load time, which as we all know, is a conversion killer.
- Google doesn’t like redirects very much (because it requires additional resources on their end).
- Have you ever tried to share an m(Dot) link with someone on a desktop? It’s a terrible experience.
- Are you going to create a new subdomain for every device? Tablets? Gaming consoles? Smart TVs?

These problems have allowed responsive design to blossom. In fact, it addresses the three main problems that plague m(Dot) sites…

- You only need to manage and optimize one site.
- Having just one URL means no redirect issues.
- Social sharing looks good again.

In fact, Google has recommended responsive design quite publicly in the past.

More info: https://www.google.com/search?q=m.dot+website